# Form Directive on submit is being ignored

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an index.php which is my Main. It contains links to Login.php, Register.php and AboutUs.php. They are linked via hyperlinks so it works fine even though they not in the same folder as expected.

Each 'called' page contains a form. Each calls a dal, to login or register or read about website. Therefore Login.php calls plogin.php which is a dal that resides in another folder for dals. The form `action="common/dals/plogin.php" method="post"`. These paths are 100% correct.

When I submit the form, the following error is generated:

> 404: Not found
>   ......common/dals/index.php

I do not understand this. It happens with all three pages.
It works if login.php & plogin.php resides in the same folder. Is this the standard, that a form control cannot cross folders? Sounds ridiculous. Anyway I have cleared the cache. Restarted my desktop. I get the same issue. I need to know if this is the standard or what can I do to resolve?

Comment: This is not common. Try ./common/dals/plogin.php

Comment: Are you submitting the form to the same file?

Answer (score -1):

1.Give beginning path, like our all projects are in htdocs suppose our project folder name is Example and this folder contain index.php and another folder images and our images folder contain one file sample.php

```
   so if you want to jump back to index.php from sample.php then write the path like this
  /Example/index.php   or
  ../index.php
```

2.Check Directories structure carefully.
3.Use ../ operator to move backward directories.
4. If you want to move back double directory back then use ../../ like this

Comment: Gentlemen, if my called page is in another folder and the return is echoed, where do I collect the data? I cannot direct the echo.

Comment: In another example if I call a web service and expect a return the page that is making the actual call has to reside in the same folder as the main page.

Comment: example: page.php  calls getData.php, getData.php calls web service and echos the data back to page.php. They have to be in the same folder as the echo cannot be directed to the folder page.php is located. In the event I save them in different folders even though the URL is correct it generates the 404 error.